# Base 64 hash to make URL shorter

Tags: php, hash, base64, hex

PHP's sha256 outputs a string which is 64 chars long because it's base 16.
How can I convert it to base 64 to reduce its length?

Comment: Instead of Base64 encoding, you may want to use [`Alphabet::convert($hash, Alphabet::HEX, Alphabet::ALPHANUMERIC)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-BaseConvert) which has the same maximum length but is URL-safe, just as `Alphabet::BASE_64_URL` and `Alphabet::BASE_58` are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
base64_encode(hash('sha256', 'hello', true));
```

Comment: the length came down from 64 to 44 chars

Comment: PHP's base64_encode() is not url-safe. Use a wrapper to fix this:
`function urlsafe_b64encode($string) {
    $data = base64_encode($string);
    $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data);
    return $data;
}`

Comment: @user703016 Okay, i want to know is that possible to decode the value after encoding? `base64_encode(hash('sha256', 'hello', true));` ??

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the hash and aren't in control of it's generation, then something like the following should work:

```php
<?php

function hex2char($c) {
  return chr(hexdec($c));
}

function char2hex($c) {
  return str_pad(dechex(ord($c)),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
}


function base16to64($v) {
  return base64_encode(implode(array_map("hex2char", str_split($v,2))));

}

function base64to16($v) {
  return implode(array_map("char2hex",str_split(base64_decode($v),1)));

}


$input = hash('sha256', 'hello');

print($input . "\n");
print(base16to64($input) . "\n");
print(base64to16(base16to64($input)) . "\n");


?>
```

returning:

```
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
LPJNul+wow4m6DsqxbninhsWHlwfp0JecwQzYpOLmCQ=
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
```

reducing the size of the hash from 64 to 44.

Answer (score 0):

<s>To convert between bases use http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php</s>

Go with the above answer, this doesn't work per the comment here.

Comment: `base_convert` doesn't accept 64 as a base. It only accepts up to 36.

Comment: point taken, answer updated so others can learn from my mistake